# EXCEL UDF dll not visible in excel adins

Tags: c#, excel, dll, user-defined-functions

I followed a tutorial on the internet for how to create udf.

Class with name 'AutomationSample' in project AutomationSample (Class library)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ExcelUdf.Automation;

namespace AutomationSample
{    
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("7CE422F9-BF1C-40B1-BD52-C9B31E09A2E2")]
    public class AutomationSample : UdfBase
    {
        public double AutomationSampleAdd(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public double AutomationSampleSubtract(double a, double b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

The class is COM-visible, and after compilation, I got dlls.

[image]

After that when I go to `Excel > Add-ins >
Choose Excel add-ins > Go > Automation`, I don't see my class on the list. What am I missing here?
I also tried manually register .dll with regasm but even after don't see it.

Even after project download from OP still doesn't work [Using C# .NET UDF](http://www.adamtibi.net/07-2012/using-c-sharp-net-user-defined-functions-udf-in-excel)

Edit: Com visible is true.

[image]

Comment: You really need the part from that sample which sets the "Programmable" registry key...

Comment: And you might need to check the `[ComVisble(true)]` attribute (or set it on the assembly).

Comment: @Govert even after editing still nothing. Edited Class http://pastebin.com/peynBpuH

Comment: You can go through my original write-up on CodeProject here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7753/Create-an-Automation-Add-In-for-Excel-using-NET

Comment: But best is to use Excel-DNA. Just install the `ExcelDna.AddIn` package from NuGet, copy the snippet from the Readme file and press F5...

Comment: @Govert I followed that tutorial on codeproject first but unsuccessfully. I would love to stick this method instead of using EXCEL-DNA just need to figure out what is problem here  I even tried to add programable key manually like this http://i67.tinypic.com/wbaqm0.png